# Javascript issue- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'incart' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to increase or decrease quantity but for some reason the increase , decrease and remove products buttons are not working. whenever I click on the icons I am seeing a error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inCart' of undefined in console.log. I have spend a lot of time but did not find the error. 
     let carts = document.querySelectorAll('.add-cart');

```
 let products = [

  {

    name:'Natural Straight',
    tag: 'naturalStraight',
    price: 95,
    incart:0
},

{

    name:'Natural Wavy',
    tag: 'naturalWavy',
    price: 200,
    incart:0
},

{

    name:'Clip in Bangs',
    tag: 'Bangs',
    price: 50,
    incart:0
},

{

    name:'Bronde Balayage',
    tag: 'brondeBalayage',
    price: 350,
    incart:0
},
```

]

```
for (let i=0; i < carts.length; i++){

carts[i].addEventListener('click',() =>{
    cartNumbers(products[i]);
    totalCost(products[i]);
})
```

}

```
 function onLoadCartNumbers()
 {
 let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers'); 

if(productNumbers){
document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = productNumbers;

}

}
 function cartNumbers(product)
 {

let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers'); 
productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);

 if(productNumbers) {
localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', productNumbers + 1); 
 document.querySelector('.cart,span').textContent=productNumbers + 1;    
 }else {

    localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers',1);  
    document.querySelector('.cart,span').textContent =1;  
 }

 setIteams(product);
}

function setIteams(product){

     let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);


    if(cartItems != null){

        if(cartItems[product.tag] == undefined){

            cartItems ={

                ...cartItems,
                [product.tag]: product
            }
        }
        cartItems[product.tag].incart += 1;
        }else {
        product.incart =1;      
     cartItems = {          
        [product.tag]: product          
    }

    } 


    localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
}



  function totalCost(product){

//  console.log("te product price is", product.price);

let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost'); 
console.log("My cartCost is", cartCost);
console.log(typeof cartCost);

if(cartCost !=null){
    cartCost = parseInt(cartCost);
    localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cartCost + product.price);

}else{

localStorage.setItem("totalCost", product.price);   
}

}
 function displayCart() {
let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

let productContainer = document.querySelector(".products");
let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost'); 

if(cartItems && productContainer) { 
    productContainer.innerHTML ='';
    Object.values(cartItems).map(item => {
    productContainer.innerHTML +=   
        ` <div class="product">
         <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon> 
         <img src="./images/${item.tag}.jpg">
          <span>${item.name}</span> 
    <div class="price">$${item.price},00</div>
    <div class="quantity">
    <ion-icon class="decrease" name="caret-back-circle-outline"></ion- 
  icon>
        <span>${item.incart}</span> 
<ion-icon class="increase" name="caret-forward-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="total">$${item.incart * item.price},00 </div>
     </div> 
        `;
    });      

}  
    manageQuantity();
   }

 function manageQuantity() {

    let decreaseButton = document.querySelectorAll('.decrease');
    let increaseButton = document.querySelectorAll('.increase'); 

    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart') //Grab all the 
     cartItems from localstorage
    let currentQuantity = 0;  
                               is 0 when we get started
    let currentProduct = " ";
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems); 
    console.log(cartItems);


   // whenever we click on them the addEventListner does some action
   for (let i=0; i < decreaseButton.length; i++) {
      decreaseButton[i].addEventListener('click', () => {

      // whenever I click on decrease button I want to know the current 
        quantity 
        currentQuantity = 
        decreaseButton[i].parentElement.querySelector('span').textContent; 
        console.log(currentQuantity);

        //replace(//g,'') -to remove place between words,g is for globally 
        everywhere on textcontent.
        currentProduct = 
        decreaseButton[i].parentElement.previousElementSibling

       .previousElementSibling.textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, 
       ''); 
        console.log(currentProduct);


        //checking cartItems and selecting the one with name and accessing  
        incart from cartItems.
   cartItems[currentProduct].incart = cartItems[currentProduct].incart -1; 
    });  
    }

 }
```

Comment: This means that `cartItems[currentProduct]` is undefined. Without the HTML markup, one cannot say more.

Comment: "let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart')" since its an object you need to parse it `let cartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('productsInCart'))`

Comment: @SaymoinSam He is already doing that.

Comment: Whenever you submit code to stack overflow, always provide console log outputs and data structures with values. Without seeing whats in the localStorage, and in variables we can't tell whats wrong.
Post the value of cartItems after it has been parsed. Post the value of currentProduct.

Comment: @RainerPlumer oh I didn't see that, I saw only the first statement

Comment: @RainerPlumer thanks for getting back to my query. I can see the console.log output for cartItems as   {naturalStraight: {…}, naturalWavy: {…}}
                            naturalStraight:
                             incart: 1
                             name: "Natural Straight"
                             price: 95
                             tag: "naturalStraight"
                             __proto__: Object

Comment: @laruiss,  I have added HTML above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that you are trying to access the value of a property from an Object that is not defined.

In your case the `cartItems[currentProduct]` Object is not defined and that is the reason you are getting the error.

This can happen because of the following things:

- `cartItems` does not contain `currenProduct`
- `currentProduct` is `undefined`
- `cartItems` itself is undefined.

But from your code it is clear that you have assigned a value for `cartItems`.
So the problem is most likely that `cartItems` does not contain `currentProduct` or `currentProduct` is `undefined`.

Check these and your code should work properly.

Comment: thanks for getting back to my query. I can see the console.log output for cartItems as   {naturalStraight: {…}, naturalWavy: {…}}
                            naturalStraight:
                             incart: 1
                             name: "Natural Straight"
                             price: 95
                             tag: "naturalStraight"
                             __proto__: Object

Comment: what does console.log(currentProduct) print ?

Comment: console.log(currentProduct) does not print anything with  .querySelector('span'), but it is printing  naturalstraight  without .querySelector('span').

Comment: So that's the problem. currentProduct is not defined so ultimately it does not fetch anything from cartItems . Fix that everything should work fine.

Comment: I tried to fix it but not able to figure out the code. can you pls help me with the working code

Comment: Post the complete code with the data structure. Then I can work on it

Comment: Thx I have edited complete code above. Pls let me know if you need more info.

Comment: @ Hari Mani  Hi any luck?